# How to animate several dots moving here and there in html canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I have a requirement to move many dots here and there inside a canvas.

Hence I created several arcs with different radius and placed them at random places.

```js
var context = document.getElementById('stage').getContext('2d');
var radian = Math.PI / 180;
var x = 40;
var y = 40;
var r = 20;
var colorPoints = [];
var frames = 50;
var currentFrame = 0;
var toggle = false;
var iconsLoaded = false;
context.beginPath();
context.arc(x,y, r, 0 * radian, 360 * radian, false)
context.fill();


var drawMultipleCurves = function(ctx){
if(!iconsLoaded){
for (let i = 0; i < 600; i++) {
    ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.filter = 'blur(5px)';
  ctx.fillStyle = '#B835FF';
  colorPoints.push({x: Math.floor((Math.random() * 700) + 0), xMove: Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 0) , yMove: Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 0) , y: Math.floor((Math.random() * 700) + 0), radius: Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 5)});
   ctx.arc(colorPoints[colorPoints.length - 1].x, colorPoints[colorPoints.length - 1].y, colorPoints[colorPoints.length - 1].radius, 0 * radian, 360 * radian, false);
   ctx.fill();
   ctx.closePath();
   iconsLoaded = true;
}
}
else{
for(let i =0;i< colorPoints.length; i++){
if(frames === currentFrame ){
    toggle = !toggle;
    currentFrame = 0;
    }
     if(!toggle){
  colorPoints[i].xMove === 1 ? colorPoints[i].x = colorPoints[i].x + 5 : colorPoints[i].x = colorPoints[i].x - 5;
                        colorPoints[i].yMove === 1 ? colorPoints[i].y = colorPoints[i].y + 5 : colorPoints[i].y = colorPoints[i].y - 5;
    }
    else{
   colorPoints[i].xMove === 1 ? colorPoints[i].x = colorPoints[i].x - 5 : colorPoints[i].x = colorPoints[i].x + 5;
                        colorPoints[i].yMove === 1 ? colorPoints[i].y = colorPoints[i].y - 5 : colorPoints[i].y = colorPoints[i].y + 5;
    }
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(colorPoints[i].x, colorPoints[i].y, colorPoints[i].radius, 0 * radian, 360 * radian, false);
                context.closePath( );
                ctx.fill();
    currentFrame = currentFrame + 1;
}
}
}

var animate = function(){
  setTimeout(()=>{
    context.clearRect(0,0,400,400);
    context.beginPath();
    drawMultipleCurves(context);
    context.fill();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  }, 1000/30)
}



 requestAnimationFrame(animate)
```

```html
<canvas id="stage" width="400" height="400">
    <p>Your browser doesn't support canvas.</p>
</canvas>
```

Above is the code that I have tried.
I have first created and placed several dots at random places with random radius.
When I created them I saved all these random places in an array 'colorPoints'

Now I'm looping into this array and moving all the dots everytime 'requestAnimation' is called.

I'm able to achieve my animation of moving the dots randomly but as I have used 800 dots and then saving them into an array and then again looping them to move their position, the animation is not looking smooth.

It looks like it is moving and strucking. How can I achieve this animation smoothly?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The main thing causing slow down is the blur. If you generate each image before you display the animation, there will be lag at the start, but the animation will be smooth.

Comment: Het @MattEllen, that's right blur is the one causing this slow down, I didn't even think that was the issue. Thanks, I'll try to fix this blur issue :)

Comment: @Harish The blur is not the full cause of the slow down, it is the combination of blur and when you call fill. Only call fill once per frame per context style. I have added answer to show how to get good performance while still using blur and `arc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Render "fill" once per style

Your code is slowing down due to where you placed `fill` (same if you use `stroke`)

When you have many objects with the same style call `fill` only once per frame for each object.

You had something like

```
  for (const c of circles) { 
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(c.x, c.y, c.r, 0, TAU) 
      ctx.fill();
  }
```

With a filter active the fill command forces the filter to be reset, which for blur is complex.

Rather add all the arcs then fill.

```
   ctx.beginPath();
   for (const c of circles) { 
      ctx.moveTo(c.x + c.r, c.y);
      ctx.arc(c.x, c.y, c.r, 0, TAU) 
   }
   ctx.fill();
```

The move `ctx.moveTo(c.x + c.r, c.y);` is used to close the previous arc.

You can also close the arc with `ctx.closePath` but this can be a lot slower when you have many arcs in the path buffer.

```
   // slower than using moveTo
   ctx.beginPath();
   for (const c of circles) { 
      ctx.arc(c.x, c.y, c.r, 0, TAU) 
      ctx.closePath();
   }
   ctx.fill();
```

### Example

Example draws 600 arcs using the blur filter as it only calls `fill` once per frame. This should run smooth on all but the most low end devices.

See function `drawCircles`

```js
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const W = canvas.width;
const BLUR = 5;
const CIRCLE_COUNT = 600;
const MIN_RADIUS = BLUR;
const MAX_RADIUS = 30;
const MAX_DELTA = 1;
const MAX_CIR_R = MAX_RADIUS + BLUR;
const MOVE_SIZE = MAX_CIR_R * 2 + W;
const TAU = 2 * Math.PI;
const setOf = (c, cb, i = 0, a = []) => { while(i < c) { a.push(cb(i++)) } return a };
const rnd = (m, M) => Math.random() * (M - m) + m;
const style = {
  filter: "blur(" + BLUR + "px)",
  fillStyle: '#B835FF',
};
var currentStyle;
function setStyle(ctx, style) {
  if (currentStyle !== style) {
    Object.assign(ctx, style);
    currentStyle = style;
  }
}

const circle = {
  get x() { return rnd(-MAX_CIR_R, W + MAX_CIR_R) }, 
  get y() { return rnd(-MAX_CIR_R, W + MAX_CIR_R)  },
  get dx() { return rnd(-MAX_DELTA, MAX_DELTA) },
  get dy() { return rnd(-MAX_DELTA, MAX_DELTA) },
  get r() { return rnd(MIN_RADIUS, MAX_RADIUS) },
  move() {
     var x = this.x + this.dx + MOVE_SIZE + MAX_CIR_R;
     var y = this.y + this.dy + MOVE_SIZE + MAX_CIR_R;
     this.x = x % MOVE_SIZE - MAX_CIR_R;
     this.y = y % MOVE_SIZE - MAX_CIR_R;
  }
};
const circles = setOf(CIRCLE_COUNT, () => Object.assign({}, circle));
function drawCircles(circles, ctx, style) {
  setStyle(ctx, style);
  ctx.beginPath();
  for (const c of circles) { 
      ctx.moveTo(c.x + c.r, c.y);
      ctx.arc(c.x, c.y, c.r, 0, TAU);
  }
  ctx.fill();
}
function updateCircles(circles) {
  for (const c of circles) { c.move(); }
}
function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,W, W);
  updateCircles(circles);
  drawCircles(circles, ctx, style);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"> </canvas>
```

If you have several colors, group all the same colors so you can keep the number of fill calls as low as possible.

There are many ways to get the same effect with many colors (each circle a different color) but will need more setup code.

Comment: Doing quite intense scatter-plots at work I'm using this technique heavily on day to day basis and I just wanted to note that since Safari 15.3 they have a very bad GPU bug where drawing a path made of more than a few hundreds circles will hang or even crash the tab. There is unfortunately no easy way to "detect" this bug, apart from some empirical test using a lot of magic numbers. Here is the one I use: https://jsfiddle.net/4ast8fej/ And from the result there, I set a "magic_number_of_circles_per_batch_threshold" to `250` or `Infinity`.

Comment: Oh and since I'm on the Safari subject, they don't support `filter` and may even never support it as it is currently defined... The simplest workaround I found is to use the `shadowOffsetX` trick to draw the shape or path outside of the canvas boundaries and keep only the blur (`shadowBlur` value should be x2)

Comment: Everything's working correctly! but how do I add 3 different colors to be applied randomly to the dots?

Answer (score 1):

The `CanvasRenderingContext2D` blur filter is quite heavy - especially if you use it on a canvas consisting of 600 circles. That means on every screen update it has to re-draw 600 circles and apply a blur filter afterwards.

The usual approach is a little different. Initially you create a master texture with a blurred circle. This texture can then be re-used and drawn onto the canvas using the `drawImage()` method. To vary the size of the circles there is no `radius` anymore though. We can get the same effect by using a `scale` instead.

Here's an example:

```js
var context = document.getElementById('stage').getContext('2d');
var radian = Math.PI / 180;
var x = 40;
var y = 40;
var r = 20;
var colorPoints = [];
var frames = 50;
var currentFrame = 0;
var toggle = false;
var iconsLoaded = false;
var texture = document.createElement("canvas");
var textureContext = texture.getContext("2d");
texture.width = 80;
texture.height = 80;
textureContext.filter = 'blur(5px)';
textureContext.fillStyle = '#B835FF';
textureContext.arc(texture.width / 2, texture.height / 2, 25, 0 * radian, 360 * radian, false);
textureContext.fill();
textureContext.closePath();

var drawMultipleCurves = function(ctx) {
    if (!iconsLoaded) {
        for (let i = 0; i < 600; i++) {
            colorPoints.push({
                x: Math.floor((Math.random() * 700) + 0),
                xMove: Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 0),
                yMove: Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 0),
                y: Math.floor((Math.random() * 700) + 0),
                scale: 0.2 + Math.random() * 0.8
            });

            iconsLoaded = true;
        }
    } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < colorPoints.length; i++) {
            if (frames === currentFrame) {
                toggle = !toggle;
                currentFrame = 0;
            }
            if (!toggle) {
                colorPoints[i].xMove === 1 ? colorPoints[i].x = colorPoints[i].x + 5 : colorPoints[i].x = colorPoints[i].x - 5;
                colorPoints[i].yMove === 1 ? colorPoints[i].y = colorPoints[i].y + 5 : colorPoints[i].y = colorPoints[i].y - 5;
            } else {
                colorPoints[i].xMove === 1 ? colorPoints[i].x = colorPoints[i].x - 5 : colorPoints[i].x = colorPoints[i].x + 5;
                colorPoints[i].yMove === 1 ? colorPoints[i].y = colorPoints[i].y - 5 : colorPoints[i].y = colorPoints[i].y + 5;
            }
            ctx.drawImage(texture, colorPoints[i].x, colorPoints[i].y, texture.width * colorPoints[i].scale, texture.height * colorPoints[i].scale);

            currentFrame = currentFrame + 1;
        }
    }
}

var animate = function() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
        context.beginPath();
        drawMultipleCurves(context);
        context.fill();
        requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    })
}



requestAnimationFrame(animate)
```

```html
  <canvas id="stage" width="400" height="400">
    <p>Your browser doesn't support canvas.</p>
</canvas>
```

Comment: `drawImage` isn't free either. For a few hundreds particles you'll already start to hit the max of what low ends devices can do, particularly the ones without GPU acceleration. A single fill + blur will outperform it by magnitudes.